# 18.04: Caja installation breaks desktop folder click access; simple resolution

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, directory, caja

**Informational Post:** I installed Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and everything worked fine. I was able to open file folders from the desktop by clicking on them, with no errors.

However, I then installed Caja. Installing Caja on Ubuntu 18.04 changes default application for handling desktop folders from Files (e.g., Nautilus) to Caja. This change of default applications will prevent you from opening desktop folders by simply clicking on them, instead requiring you to constantly open them using the right-click context menu and "Open with other application" selection.

In order to restore the original functionality for opening desktop folders by simply clicking on them, you must reassign the default application Files (Nautilus) as the application for opening files. I was unable to find a method to do this in the hybrid Nautilus/Caja environment I had created, so I chose to remove Caja and reassert Nautilus as the default file manager.

To restore the original functionality for opening desktop folders:

1. Remove caja:

   `sudo apt remove caja`
2. Reinstall Nautilus:

   `sudo apt install nautilus`

2a. Re-installation will notify you that there are some files remaining from the Caja installation;

2b. It will also notify you to run autoremove:

```
`sudo apt autoremove`
```

4. autoremove will Uninstall remaining Caja (and other) unnecessary modules.
5. I rebooted.
6. Desktop folders open as they originally did.

Problem solved.

Comment: I can recommend to switch the whole desktop to MATE by installing `ubuntu-mate-desktop` meta-package. This will solve the major issue of GNOMEs Hell.